# SQL Dynamic Pivot only using SELECT

Tags: sql, subquery, pivot

Where I work, we can only use "Read only" capabilities for SQL - I'm stuck using "SELECT" statements for everything.  I find workarounds to create higher level outputs but this one has me stumped and I honestly don't know if it's possible.  I don't know what version of SQL this is, I'm sorry.

Is there any way to "PIVOT" data dynamically while only using SELECT, and without using any Declaration statements?

Here's what I'm working with:
MyTable has 3 main fields I need to reference, CAT_ID, USER_ID and OPT. (Category, User, and option)

```
SELECT
    CAT_ID,
    USER_ID,
    "1" = SUM( IIF(OPT = '1' , 1,0)),
    "2" = SUM( IIF(OPT = '2' , 1,0)),
    "3" = SUM( IIF(OPT = '3' , 1,0)),
    A = SUM( IIF(OPT = 'A' , 1,0)),
    B = SUM( IIF(OPT = 'N' , 1,0)),
    C = SUM( IIF(OPT = 'U' , 1,0))
FROM myTable
WHERE CAT_ID = 'CAT A'
GROUP BY  CAT_ID, USER_ID
```

Output produces a matrix that I can use to quickly ID what capabilities a user has in a specific category.
The goal is to use this output to help audit our users to make sure my workers have set people up correctly for the job they use.

```
CAT_ID  USER_ID 0   1   2   3   A   B   C
CAT A   USER1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
CAT A   USER2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
CAT A   USER3   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
CAT A   USER4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
CAT A   USER5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I thought about maybe creating a temp table list of the options to use as a subquery but I'm not sure if that's doable with pivot. What I tried certainly didn't work.

```
SELECT * INTO #OPTIONS FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT OPT FROM myTable)
 AS OPTIONS

SELECT * FROM myTable MT
PIVOT (
  COUNT(CAT_ID)
  FOR MT.OPT
  IN (SELECT OPT FROM #OPTIONS)
  ) AS PTTBL
```

But as I said, this doesn't work.  What else can I try, or did I simply make a mistake?

Comment: You can't do a dynamic pivot without a dynamic query. Unless what you want is really a static one, in that case you can afford to have a single select statement.

Comment: Make sure to read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the [tips for asking a good sql question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). It's difficult to understand what your inputs and expected outputs are within your post, as well as the DBMS you're dealing with (at first sight it looks like SQL Server, but not fully sure).